# media player array crash casually

Tags: android, random, android-mediaplayer

I've build this app, that is a simple mediaplayer. I have a button and when I push it I play a random song from the MediaPlayer array.
I have a problem with the code: casually when I push that button my app crash and restart on the tablet. It looks like there is no rules with this problem. I have the problem sometimes with the song 20, another with the 4 etc etc.
The song are about 8/9mb everyone. Is a problem of memory?
I need to store the songs on the tablet and not on the app? If it is how can I do it? I've tried to reduce the weight of the mp3 file but it doesn't resolve the problem.

[image]

```
public class Activity_Ascolta extends AppCompatActivity {

    final Context context = this;

    int flag = 0;

    final MediaPlayer [] mpList = new MediaPlayer[50];

    float volumecorrente = (float) (1 - (Math.log(100 - 50) / Math.log(100)));

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Remove title bar
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        //Remove notification bar
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        //set content view AFTER ABOVE sequence (to avoid crash)
        this.setContentView(R.layout.layout_ascolta);

        setContentView(R.layout.layout_ascolta);

        final int MAX_VOLUME = 100;
        SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sb_volume);

        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                float volume = (float) (1 - (Math.log(MAX_VOLUME - progress) / Math.log(MAX_VOLUME)));
                mpList[flag].setVolume(volume, volume);
                volumecorrente = volume;
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });

        TextView tv_sopra = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_ascolta_1);
        TextView tv_sotto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_ascolta_2);
        TextView tv_apprezza = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_ascolta_3);

        SharedPreferences scelta_lingua = getSharedPreferences("pref_lingua", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = scelta_lingua.edit();
        String lingua_corrente = scelta_lingua.getString("pref_lingua", "");

        if (lingua_corrente.compareTo("italiano") == 0) {
            tv_sopra.setText("ASCOLTA");
            tv_sotto.setText("LA MUSICA");
            tv_apprezza.setText("APPREZZA LE DIFFERENZE DI OGNI CUFFIA");
        } else if (lingua_corrente.compareTo("inglese") == 0) {
            tv_sopra.setText("LISTEN");
            tv_sotto.setText("TO THE MUSIC");
            tv_apprezza.setText("APPRECIATES THE DIFFERENCES OF EACH HEADSET");
        }

        ImageButton returnHome = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.img_btt_return_home_ascolto);
        returnHome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (mpList != null) {mpList[flag].release();}

                final Intent toHome = new Intent(Activity_Ascolta.this, Activity_Home.class);
                startActivity(toHome);

            }
        });

        ImageButton playMusic = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.img_btt_play_music);
        playMusic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                /*final Intent toMediaPlayer = new Intent(Activity_Ascolta.this,Activity_MediaPlayer.class);
                startActivity(toMediaPlayer);*/

                if (mpList != null) {mpList[flag].release();}

                //generate random number
                Random randomGenerator = new Random();
                int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(mpList.length);

                Log.e("Random" , String.valueOf(randomInt));
                mpList[randomInt].start();
                mpList[randomInt].setVolume(volumecorrente,volumecorrente);
                flag = randomInt;

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart () {

        super.onStart();
        loadingSongs();

    }

    public void loadingSongs (){

        mpList [0] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.a24k_magic);
        mpList [1] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.abbaon_fat_tracks);
        mpList [2] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.after_the_afterlife);
        mpList [3] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.amalia);
        mpList [4] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.amerimacka);
        mpList [5] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.angels);
        mpList [6] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.anymore);
        mpList [7] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.baby_gurl_original_mix);
        mpList [8] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.back_home);
        mpList [9] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.beautiful_escape_feat_zak_a);
        mpList [10] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.better_with_you);
        mpList [11] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.black_jeans_vocal_mix);
        mpList [12] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.body_music);
        mpList [13] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.born_to_run);
        mpList [14] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.brother_john);
        mpList [15] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.bye_bye_boy);
        mpList [16] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.cloud_9);
        mpList [17] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.daddy_s_groove);
        mpList [18] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.don_t_go);
        mpList [19] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.down_the_road_irfane_remix);
        mpList [20] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.down_to_the_sound);
        mpList [21] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.eye_of_the_tiger);
        mpList [22] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.fly_feat_kelsey);
        mpList [23] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.glad_edit);
        mpList [24] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.i_can_see_clearly_now);
        mpList [25] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.i_don_t_wanna_live_forever_fifty_shades_darker);
        mpList [26] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.jump);
        mpList [27] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.kill_it_tonight_feat_ice_mc);
        mpList [28] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.kindling_for_the_master_majo);
        mpList [29] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.lady_divine);
        mpList [30] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.life_round_here);
        mpList [31] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.make_you_feel);
        mpList [32] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.melt_away_original_mix);
        mpList [33] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.midnight_feast);
        mpList [34] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.palace_posy);
        mpList [35] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.pirates_of_samba_oxio_radio);
        mpList [36] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.pledge_allegiance_the_rimsho);
        mpList [37] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.queen_of_the_night_feat_nik);
        mpList [38] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.set_me_free_feat_alexandra_p);
        mpList [39] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.sister_welcome);
        mpList [40] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.space_walk);
        mpList [41] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.the_sweetest);
        mpList [42] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.to_get_up_with_you_remix);
        mpList [43] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.towers_feat_szjerdene);
        mpList [44] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.traveling_miles);
        mpList [45] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.tricks_main_vocal_original);
        mpList [46] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.ugly_brotha_real_nices_pri);
        mpList [47] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.wanting_you);
        mpList [48] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.we_just_couldnt_say_goodbye);
        mpList [49] = MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Ascolta.this, R.raw.you_d_be_so_nice_to_come_home);

        return ;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by the word "casually"? Does this mean that the described problem occurs some of the time, but not all of the time after start button is clicked?

Comment: I mean that when I push this button for the first time the media player starts, if I push another time the button the player changes the song but if I keep pushing the "play" button it starts playing songs randomly and then suddenly it crashes and the app re-start again. What's the problem in your opinion?

Comment: Adding diagnostic code that logs events and state transitions is often helpful to solving problems like this that do not appear to behave in a deterministic manner.

Comment: @JohnH what do you think is good to write as diagnostic code in this case?